# Where to put #define in IPython Cython cell?

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, cython

If I make a notebook with cells

```
%load_ext cython
```

and

```
%%cython -a

cimport numpy as cnp
```

then the second one outputs

```
In file included from /home/ignoring_gravity/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1960,
                 from /home/ignoring_gravity/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                 from /home/ignoring_gravity/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:5,
                 from /home/ignoring_gravity/.cache/ipython/cython/_cython_magic_7ec32efe76f8c3e83109f4fadb9a4e1f.c:765:
/home/ignoring_gravity/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
   17 | #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
      |  ^~~~~~~
```

My question is - where should I put`#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION`? If I change the second cell to

```
%%cython -a

#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
cimport numpy as cnp
```

then it still gives the same warning

Comment: It doesn't really matter - it's only a warning. You don't have to put `#define` anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cython-magic doesn't have arguments to define or un-define a macro, but one could do by adding the following line:

```
%%cython -a
# distutils: define_macros=NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION

cimport numpy as cnp
```

However, until Cython 3.0, the deprecated numpy-API was used and getting rid of this warning would/could lead to issues. Thus, for Cython's versions <= 3.0 one should follow @DavidW's advice and ignore the warning.

See also a related note in the [Cython's documentation.](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/migrating_to_cy30.html#numpy-c-api)